# How to add padding to the logo in launch screen?

Tags: android, nativescript, pinterest

[image: Desired outcome]

I would like to add padding or space to the logo on both the sides and the code is added here.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:gravity="fill">
        <item android:drawable="@color/ns_theme"></item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/logo" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

Comment: share your xml code

Comment: Use android:left="10dp" and android:right="10dp" on your item
http://idunnolol.com/android/drawables.html#layer-list

Comment: This code i tried but its not working

Comment: Wrap the bitmap inside an inset drawable and set your padding there

Comment: @Bala did you ever find a solution to this? Can you accept my answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, I tried to add padding to the item but it didn't change anything.

```
   <item
        android:left="16dp"
        android:right="16dp">
        <bitmap android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/splash"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>
   </item>
```

The problem was gravity="center", with it the padding were not applied.

Try using android: gravity = "clip_horizontal"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/splash_color" />
    
    <item
        android:left="16dp"
        android:right="16dp">
        <bitmap android:gravity="clip_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/splash"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: After a few hours of research, that was the answer which helped me. clip_horizontal is the key.

Answer (score 3):

Use

- **`android:bottom=""`**
- **`android:left=""`**
- **`android:right=""`**
- **`android:top=""`**

Try this

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="fill">
    <item android:drawable="@color/ns_theme"></item>
    <item
        android:bottom="20dp"
        android:left="20dp"
        android:right="20dp"
        android:top="20dp">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: @Bala you can see the changes in preview while setting this

Comment: if I use only android:left="20dp" and android:right="20dp", the space is coming but the image is stretching from top to bottom.

Comment: @Bala share any screen shot of your expected output

Comment: I shared the screenshot of expected output.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/ns_theme" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_logo"
        android:left="@dimen/_16sdp"
        android:right="@dimen/_16sdp" />
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Using android:drawable did the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that your logo is too big (The image file you are using has a pixel width that exceeds the pixel density of the device you are running it on).

Whether or not that is the case, it would probably be better to approach the problem considering the possibility that it could be run on ANY Android device with ANY screen size.

Considering that, there are several options better than simply adding padding in xml... For example, you could:

1) Wrap the image inside another view object that you can control the size and postion of as Bhavik Makwana suggested.

2) Just simply re-edit/resample your image to match the width of your target device and include the white space you desire in the image itself.

3) Design full splash screens that match the entire screen exactly (which combine foreground and background into one image), for example one with 1080 x 1920 resolution, and others for other screen sizes.  That way you can control exactly how you want it to look, and the resolution will be 1-1 with no anti-aliasing or resampling.

4) Use [this](http://www.tidev.io/2014/02/12/android-splash-screens-using-9-patch-images/) "9-patch" image approach to define an absolute width and height for your logo, but allow stretching of the white space around it to accommodate different screen sizes.

or, finally, the best way:

5) Use a constraint layout with guidelines in order to define the width of your logo in terms of percentage of parent width rather than absolute value.

Some other advice:  Unless you are using technique #2 above, make sure you are using a logo.png file like this:

[image]

... NOT like this:

[image]

KaBOOYOW!

-Boober.

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

  <item
      android:bottom="10dp"
      android:left="10dp"
      android:right="10dp"
      android:top="10dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:background="@mipmap/logo" />

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />

<item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:gravity="center" />

</item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: This code is working fine in my device please recheck your xml code.